# about construction of simultaneous test envelope

Tags: bootstrap, simulation, qq-plot

According to Davison and Hinkley's book "Bootstrap Methods and their Application", page 154, based on an `RxN` array where `R=999` is the number of simulations and `N` is the number of ordered samples (smallest to largest) in each row, we could construct:

1. **pointwise** test envelope: by extracting the 2.5th and 97.5th quantile of each column, and then connect the `N` (ordered) dots
2. **simultaneous** test envelope: "we first compute **columnwise ranks**. Then we calculate the proportion of rows in which either the minimum rank is less than or equal to `k`, or the maximum rank is greater than or equal to `R + 1 — k`, or both"

Here `k = p(R+1) = 0.05*(999+1) = 50` and `R + 1 - k = 950`. I am confused about the construction of #2 "simultaneous test envelope" above (the explanation is unclear to me...) -- can it be directly made with the `R x N` matrix? Could anyone help me in explaining the procedure in detail? Thanks!

Here is the plot that shows both the pointwise (dashed) and simultaneous (solid) envelopes from the book:

[image]